# Qiskit in Julia language?

Tags: qiskit

Is it possible to use Qiskit in Julia language? Or is there any wrapper that can be used to call the package from Julia language?

Comment: For those interested in what a Julia languge is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_(programming_language)

Answer (score 7):

Using [PyCall](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl) it is possible to use arbitrary Python packages (such as Qiskit) in Julia and use the Python functions. At least, this is what PyCall advertises to be able.

What you describe has been done before: [here](https://github.com/Roger-luo/quantum-benchmarks/blob/master/bin/utils/info.jl) is an example on GitHub.

Essentially, you would need to do this (I haven't tried this out myself):

```
using PyCall
qiskit = pyimport("qiskit")
```

Qiskit recommends using Jupyter. Jupyter includes Julia, so it would be convenient to use this.

I did a search for a native Julia qiskit wrapper, but I did not found one.