# Use Qiskit in other programming languages (C#, JavaScript and Lua)

Tags: qiskit

I am exploring using Qiskit in other programming languages for game development, such as C# (for Unity game engine), JavaScript (Phaser.io) and Lua (LÖVE2D).

Is there a general way to call Qiskit class and methods from other programming languages? Perhaps this is a question related to python and not specific to Qiskit. But I think it still has values in this stackexchange for people want to develop applications in other languages using Qiskit.

The answer for Julia: [Qiskit in Julia language?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9360/qiskit-in-julia-language) is related but not the same. I have edited the question for C#, JavaScript and Lua specifically.

Comment: A related question about using Qiskit in Julia: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9360/qiskit-in-julia-language

Comment: Call python from JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175510/call-python-function-from-javascript-code

Comment: Call python from C# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-c

Comment: Another approach is to use flask server in python, but that requires writing the APIs individually. I am looking for a way to call any or most of qiskit modules without writing a lot of new code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qiskit in Julia language?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9360/qiskit-in-julia-language)

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the comment. But the answer is only for Julia. I want to know the solution for C#, Javascript and Lua.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be converted to required Programming language. 
[Py4J](https://www.py4j.org/) , Py4J enables Python programs running in a Python interpreter to dynamically access Java objects in a Java Virtual Machine.  
[SWIG](http://swig.org) is a software development tool that connects programs written in C and C++ with a variety of high-level programming languages.